# OpenGL Render Sphere Without Glut: What is wrong with this implementation?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

In my rendering loop I have the following logic. I have other things render to the screen, and they render, (I removed that code to get right to the point). This code does not render a sphere, and I can't figure out why not. Am I missing something in the math? I have stepped through with the debugger and the values seem right. Note mBubbleDiameter is 20 as set in the constructor of this object.

```
static GLfloat staticDegreesToRadians(GLfloat tmpDegrees) {
    return tmpDegrees * ((std::atan(1.0f)*4)/180.0f);
}

void LedPannelWidget::updateGL() {
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();

        glViewport(0, 0, mWidth, mHeight);
        glOrtho(0, mWidth, 0, mHeight, -mBubbleDiameter, mBubbleDiameter);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glScissor(0, 0, mWidth, mHeight);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glClearColor(0.92f, 0.92f, 0.92f, 1.0);

        glLoadIdentity();
    const GLfloat tmpRadius = mDiameter/2.0f;
    const GLfloat tmpDelta = 5.00f;
    const GLfloat tmpDeltaRadians = staticDegreesToRadians(tmpDelta);

    for (int32_t tmpTheta = 180; tmpTheta > 0; tmpTheta -= tmpDelta) {
        for (int32_t tmpPhi = 0; tmpPhi < 360; tmpPhi += tmpDelta) {
            GLfloat tmpThetaRadians = staticDegreesToRadians(tmpTheta);
            GLfloat tmpPhiRadians = staticDegreesToRadians(tmpTheta);

            GLfloat tmpX1 = tmpRadius *
                std::sin(tmpThetaRadians) * 
                std::cos(tmpPhiRadians); 
            GLfloat tmpY1 = tmpRadius *
                std::sin(tmpThetaRadians) *
                std::cos(tmpPhiRadians);
            GLfloat tmpZ1 = tmpRadius *
                std::cos(tmpThetaRadians);

            GLfloat tmpX2 = tmpRadius *
                std::sin(tmpThetaRadians - tmpDeltaRadians) * 
                std::cos(tmpPhiRadians);
            GLfloat tmpY2 = tmpRadius *
                std::sin(tmpThetaRadians - tmpDeltaRadians) *
                std::cos(tmpPhiRadians); 
            GLfloat tmpZ2 = tmpRadius *
                std::cos(tmpThetaRadians - tmpDeltaRadians);

            GLfloat tmpX3 = tmpRadius * 
                std::sin(tmpThetaRadians - tmpDeltaRadians) *
                std::cos(tmpPhiRadians + tmpDeltaRadians);
            GLfloat tmpY3 = tmpRadius *
                std::sin(tmpThetaRadians - tmpDeltaRadians) *
                std::cos(tmpPhiRadians + tmpDeltaRadians);
            GLfloat tmpZ3 = tmpRadius *
                std::cos(tmpThetaRadians - tmpDeltaRadians);

            GLfloat tmpX4 = tmpRadius *  
                std::sin(tmpThetaRadians) *
                std::cos(tmpPhiRadians + tmpDeltaRadians);

            GLfloat tmpY4 = tmpRadius *
                std::sin(tmpThetaRadians) *
                std::cos(tmpPhiRadians + tmpDeltaRadians);

            GLfloat tmpZ4 = tmpRadius *
                std::cos(tmpThetaRadians);

            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                glVertex3f(tmpX1, tmpY1, tmpZ1);
                glVertex3f(tmpX2, tmpY2, tmpZ2);
                glVertex3f(tmpX3, tmpY3, tmpZ3);
                glVertex3f(tmpX4, tmpY4, tmpZ4);
            glEnd();

            if (tmpGLError != GL_NO_ERROR) {
                QApplication::exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
    swapBuffers();
}
```

---

Working GL Algorithm:

```
const GLfloat r = mDiameter/2.0f;
const GLfloat phid = 20.00f;
const GLfloat thetad = 20.00f;
const GLfloat x = mCenterXCoord;
const GLfloat y = mCenterYCoord;

using namespace std;
for (int32_t phi = 180; phi > 0; phi -= phid) {
    int32_t theta = 0;
    GLfloat rphi = staticDegreesToRadians(phi);
    GLfloat rtheta = staticDegreesToRadians(theta);
    glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);
    glColor3f(mCurrentColor.red()/255.0, mCurrentColor.green()/255.0,
        mCurrentColor.blue()/255.0);
    glVertex3f(
        (x + (r * sin(rphi) * cos(rtheta))),
        (y + (r * cos(rphi))),
        (0 + (r * sin(rphi) * cos(rtheta))));
    glVertex3f(
        (x + (r * sin(rphi + phid) * cos(rtheta))),
        (y + (r * cos(rphi + phid))),
        (0 + (r * sin(rphi + phid) * cos(rtheta))));

    for (; theta < 360; theta += thetad) {
        rtheta = staticDegreesToRadians(theta);
        glVertex3f(
            (x + (r * sin(rphi + phid) * cos(rtheta + thetad))),
            (y + (r * cos(rphi + phid))),
            (0 + (r * sin(rphi + phid) * cos(rtheta + thetad))));
        glVertex3f(
            (x + (r * sin(rphi) * cos(rtheta + thetad))),
            (y + (r * cos(rphi))),
            (0 + (r * sin(rphi) * cos(rtheta + thetad))));
    }
    glEnd();
}
```

Comment: you are using a deprecated approach and you are using functions that aren't available in OpenGL 3.1 and newer, this is a similar scenario http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/34109/18802 to give you an idea.

Comment: The project I am writing this for does not allow VBOs, shaders, or any of the extensions. I am writing this to an opengl 2.0 based environment. Your comment is appreciated though. And I don't have access to glut, nor am I allowed to use it.

Comment: You could improve it using triangle strips (with a fan on top and bottom).

Comment: Yes I could but I would like to get it working first. Nothing appears on the screen when I use my code. But I don't see anyting wrong with the math. I have done it all out by hand and cross checked my computations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your code in these lines

```
       GLfloat tmpThetaRadians = staticDegreesToRadians(tmpTheta);
        GLfloat tmpPhiRadians = staticDegreesToRadians(tmpTheta);

        GLfloat tmpX1 = tmpRadius *
            std::sin(tmpThetaRadians) * 
            std::cos(tmpPhiRadians); 
        GLfloat tmpY1 = tmpRadius *
            std::sin(tmpThetaRadians) *
            std::cos(tmpPhiRadians);
        GLfloat tmpZ1 = tmpRadius *
            std::cos(tmpThetaRadians);
```

You need changes see below

```
       GLfloat tmpThetaRadians = staticDegreesToRadians(tmpTheta);
       GLfloat tmpPhiRadians = staticDegreesToRadians(tmpPhi);
       GLfloat tmpX1 = tmpRadius *
            std::sin(tmpThetaRadians) * 
            std::sin(tmpPhiRadians); 
        GLfloat tmpY1 = tmpRadius *
            std::sin(tmpThetaRadians) *
            std::cos(tmpPhiRadians);
        GLfloat tmpZ1 = tmpRadius *
            std::cos(tmpThetaRadians);
```

Comment: According to my math book(s) the formula is:
    x=r \, \sin\theta \, \cos\varphi \quad 
    y=r \, \sin\theta \, \sin\varphi \quad 
    z=r \, \cos\theta \quad

Comment: you are saying  y=r \, \sin\theta \, \sin\varphi \quad  but using  y=r \, \sin\theta \, \cos\varphi \quad in above your code. I have also render the sphere same like your are doing you can see here http://codeincodeblock.blogspot.com/2011/06/texture-map-in-solid-sphere-using.html it is working fine. This program is in c++ and OpenGL(GLUT)

Comment: we are approaching the problem in a very simlar manner, however even after making your suggested changes it is a no go. If I repost my code could you take a second look at it?

Comment: @MatthewHoggan share your complete code  I will download it and try solve problem

Comment: See the code above, my big mistake was forgetting that the z axis is what points out of the screen, and the y points up.